# BufferedReader - Search for string inside .txt file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying, using a BufferedReader to count the appearances of a string inside a .txt file. I am using:

```
File file = new File(path);
try {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String line;
  int appearances = 0;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      if (line.contains("Hello")) {
         appearances++;
      }
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Found " + appearances);
```

But the problem is that if my .txt file contains for example the string `"Hello, world\nHello, Hello, world!"` and `"Hello"` is to be found then the appearances become two instead of three because it searches a line for only one appearance of the string. How could I fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your question before posting it - use the preview to see what your post will look like, and ask yourself whether it's looking as good as it can before you post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to do

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    appearances += line.split("Hello", -1).length-1;
```

Note that, if instead of "Hello", you search for anything with [regex-reserved characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), you should escape the string before splitting:

```
String escaped = Pattern.quote("Hello."); // avoid '.' special meaning in regex
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    appearances += line.split(escaped, -1).length-1;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, as it will not count leading or trailing `"Hello"`. For example, the length of "Hello Hello".split("Hello") is `1` instead of `3`

Comment: Oops - accidentally downvoted; my benchmark (see my answer) used a ".1" string as "something found very often". Unluckily, it is a regex, you are not escaping it, and that was leading to "wrong" results. Editing your question to revert my vote.

Answer (score 2):

This is an efficent and correct solution:

```
String line;
int count = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)    
    int index = -1;
    while((index = line.indexOf("Hello",index+1)) != -1){
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

It walks through the line and looks for the next index, starting from the previous index+1.

The problem with Peter's solution is that it is wrong (see my comment). The problem with TheLostMind's solution is that it creates a lot of new strings by replacement which is an unnecessary performance drawback.

Comment: Faster than regexes, and both faster and more correct than splits

Answer (score 1):

A regex-driven version:

```
String line;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("Hello")); // quotes in case you need 'Hello.'
int count = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)    
    for (Matcher m = p.matcher(line); m.find(); count ++) { }
}
return count;
```

I am now curious as to performance between this and gexicide's version - will edit when I have results.

---

EDIT: benchmarked by running 100 times on a ~800k log file, looking for strings that were found once at the start, once around middle-ish, once at the end, and several times throughout. Results:

```
IndexFinder: 1579ms, 2407200hits. // gexicide's code
RegexFinder: 2907ms, 2407200hits. // this code
SplitFinder: 5198ms, 2407200hits. // Peter Lawrey's code, after quoting regexes
```

**Conclussion: for non-regex strings, the repeated-indexOf approach is fastest by a nice margin.**

Essential benchmark code (log file from vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 installation):

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
    Finder[] fs = new Finder[] {
        new SplitFinder(), new IndexFinder(), new RegexFinder()};
    File log = new File("/var/log/dpkg.log.1"); // around 800k in size
    Find test = new Find();
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        for (Finder f : fs) {
            test.test(f, log, "2014"); // start
            test.test(f, log, "gnome"); // mid
            test.test(f, log, "ubuntu1"); // end
            test.test(f, log, ".1"); // multiple; not at start
        }
    }
    test.printResults();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (line.contains("Hello")) { // search until line has "Hello"
 appearances++;
 line = line.replaceFirst("Hello",""); // replace first occurance of "Hello" with empty String
 }
```

Comment: This is much slower than the other approaches; for a long line, it is O(n^2) instead of O(n)